# How do I allow a Java applet which I accidentally denied?

Tags: macos, safari, java-applet

How do I allow a Java applet which I accidentally denied?

I'm using Mac OS X and Safari.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try resetting Safari under the Safari menu and then restarting your Mac.

[image]

Comment: Seems to have worked thank you very much :-)

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to

> Applications/Utilities/Java
>   Preferences

Under the

> Network Tab

click

> View Cache Files

You may be able to re-allow the applet to run from there.

Comment: it isn't showing up there.

Comment: What applet is it ?

Comment: it's a java based game supremacy1914